# Python: How to display Pandas DataFrame to a Gtk TreeView widget made in Glade

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, gnome, glade

I am building a UI where I can allow the user to manipulate data and select the parameters they wish to use. I am having trouble displaying the Pandas DataFrame to the TreeView widget that was made I made in Glade.

Below is my Glade XML file that contains the Gtk TreeView widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.19.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTreeView" id="AllDataTreeView">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child internal-child="selection">
          <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection1"/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

And here is my Python script that calls and builds the Gtk-Glade UI, with the Pandas DataFrame I would like to display.

```
import pandas as pd

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

#%% dataframe to be displayed:
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


#%%

class Handler:
#############################    
##  INITIALIZATIONS/EXITS  ##
#############################  
    def __init__(self): #initializes the glade file used as well as any windows or text/image viewers#
        self.gladefile = "ShowDataExample.glade"
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("MainWindow")
        # TreeView
        self.AllDataTreeView = self.builder.get_object("AllDataTreeView")
        # show glade setup
        self.window.show()

    def on_gtk_quit_activate(self, menuitem, data=None): #closes window when you click on quit from the file chooser#
        print "quit from menu"
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args): #closes window when you click on the x at the top of the window#
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)       




if __name__ == "__main__": #Calls on the UI#
  main = Handler()
  Gtk.main()
```

Any input, or links to useful examples would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for someone.
It should work without glade UI.

```
#import
import pandas as pd
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

class PandasViewer(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="PandasViewer")

        # Create a layout
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing = 6)
        self.add(self.box)

        # Create the ListStore model
        self.pd_ls_model = Gtk.ListStore(str, float, float)
        for row in df.itertuples():
        self.pd_ls_model.append(list(row))
        # Create the TreeView and add the columns
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.pd_ls_model)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(df.columns, start=1):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column   = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)

        # Place TreeView inside the layout
        self.box.add(self.treeview)
        self.show()

win = PandasViewer()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please consider adding more explanations to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look about Gtk.TreeView at https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treeview.html

```
# create model like this
store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str)

# fill it with your data
for row in df.itertuples():
    store.append([row[0], row[1], row[2]])

# set it as TreeView model
self.AllDataTreeView.set_model(store)

# Create and append columns
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns, start=1):
    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(col, renderer, text=i)
    self.AllDataTreeView.append_column(col)

# in yours init function change from this
self.window.show()
# to this
self.window.show_all()
```

And you should be fine

Comment: I did. I'm still having problems connecting my liststore to the TreeView widget in my Glade UI.

Comment: Should be self.AllDataTreeView.append_column(column)